# Why UIActionSheet init method accepts an array of string instead of a NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

this is really a newbie question, but it would help me to have a better understanding of how Objective-c works. I have made use of UIActionSheet in a iOS app. Looking at documentation this is the relevant init method:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title delegate:(id < UIActionSheetDelegate >)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
```

Where otherButtonTitles is said to be a comma separated list of NSString. In my mind this is correspondent to an NSArray, so with the intent of caushing a crash I tried:

```
NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"B1",@"B2",nil];
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Actions" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:buttons];
```

And then obviously the application crashed because of buttons NSArray.
This sounds so similiar to Java varargs, where in a class you can have something like:

```
public void myMethod(String... param) {...};
```

A legal call to this method is:

```
myClass.myMethod("x");
myClass.myMethod("x","Y");
```

I have a lot of methods in my iOS apps that made use of NSArray:

```
[myClass myMethod:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:....]];
```

And it would be very convenient for me to avoid alloc of NSArray but rather passing a comma separated list of NSString. How can I do that ? I mean, from the myMethod point of view, what type of param is received and how should it be considered ? For example how can I cycle trough an NSString ???

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the king of Objective-c newbie as I am, here comes a little misundertanding for me. As pointed out by Graham, the method made indeed use of variable arguments. At first glance I completely missing this, the Java varargs notation has this equivalent in Objective-c:

```
public void myMethod(String... var);
-(void)myMethod:(NSString*)var,...;
```

Infact if you take a look at UIActionSheet method signature it put exactly the same three dot notation in the part regarding other buttons:

```
otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
```

Also for dealing with variable arguments in objective-c I found a very useful link:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html

Coming to my question, I can safely rewrite all my methods by implementing the 'three dot notation', and throw away all the unnecessary NSArray.

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, the following should work:

```
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Actions" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"B1",@"B2",nil];
```

It's no more complicated than it sounds. A "comma-separated list of NSString" is nothing more than a list of NSStrings, separated by commas.

Comment: uhm, probably it crashes because of something else. But, why the param in UIActionSheet is not marked as (NSArray*)otherButtonTitles ?

Comment: Because it doesn't take an array, it takes a comma-separated list of NSString.

Comment: Sorry, I read your answer again, this is not was I was asking at first instance. I know that your example works, infact this is how I set it up. But I wanted to understand why a signature of NSString can also be a "comma separated NSString", and not only an NSString. I am trying to find evidence of this in documentation, and how in case of custom method can I parse the comma separeted list.

Comment: In particular, just a little OT, this could be quite useful in case of dynamic creation of button. For example, how can I write something like NSString *dynamicButtons = [<whatever can be written here> @"x",@"x2",nil]; and then otherButtonsTitles=dynamicButtons ?

Comment: This latest comment has a bad example, that can be solved easily withAddButtonWithTitle, but I hope I made the concept clear.

Comment: It can't be. The signature is not "NSString", it's "NSString, ...". The ... is important. Search Google for variadic functions.

Comment: That's right !!! I completely misunderstood the ',...' as convenience for the writer, rather than a signature. Coming from a java background I would have expected something as (NSString* ...), I found a good article on variadic in objective-c "http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html". If you could rewrite your answer possibly with a comparison to java varargs notation I can mark as solved. Thanks

Comment: Eh? You've solved your problem, why should I rewrite my answer now?